# Django sql use regex to check the phone number

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a number 
`number1 = '0987654321'`

In my Place model,I have a filed phone saved with '0987-654-321' or maybe '0987-654321' or maybe extacly '0987654321' ...

I want to check `this field` and `number1` is they are the same thing

Is there any method to do regex in django queryset like this situation?

Now my method is use for loop to check:

```
phonenumbers = Place.objects.filter(phone__isnull=False)
for phone in phonenumbers:
    number = phone.phone_set.all()[0].phone 
    numbers =  re.findall(r'\d+', number)
    numbers =  "".join(numbers)   #0987654321
    if  number1 == numbers:
        print 'find repeat item'
    else:
        print 'nothing found'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the `-` in the number present in the field with empty string and check the resultant string with the original string for equality.

```
>>> number1 = '0987654321'
>>> s = '0987-654-321'
>>> if s.replace('-', '') == number1:
        print("equal")
    else:
        print('Not equal')


    equal
```

Comment: I mean can I do queryset like ````Place.objects.filter(phone__afterregex =number1 )````?